# PRAW: export to data table with pandas or other; open to suggestions

Tags: python, pandas, praw

I have the following code which uses a python script, calls praw and returns text from a reddit page. I now want to:

Be able to get more comments as it only outputs a small amount. 
I want the see the response tree to the comments.
I want to export the contents of the data to a table
I wantto export this to a .csv

I'm new to this, so any advice is helpful. Thanks!

```
import praw
import datetime as dt

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=,agent_id=,etc. )

submission = reddit.submission(id='7v8ob2')

comments = submission.comments

for comment in comments:
    print(20*'-')
    print('Parent ID:', comment.parent)
    print('Comment ID:', comment.id)
    print('Score:', comment.score)
    print('Created:', comment.created)
    print('Body:', comment.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df_rows = [[comment.parent, comment.id, comment.score, comment.created, comment.body] for comment in comments]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_rows, columns=['Parent ID', 'Comment ID', 'Score', 'Created', 'Body'])
df.to_csv('path_to_save_to.csv')
```

**EDIT**:
Under the assumption that you have no ability to expand the attributes of all the objects in the comments generator at once, you have to iterate over all the comments and expand each comment to retrieve its attributes.

I put all the data in a list because to quote the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/merging.html#concatenating-objects):

> concat (and therefore append) makes a full copy of the data, and that constantly reusing this function can create a signifcant performance hit. If you need to use the operation over several datasets, use a list comprehension.

Placing all the data in a list beforehand (using list comprehension) avoids this performance hit.

Comment: Hi @ec2604! Thanks for the reply. I do need some more context I ran the code attached above and got the following error: 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I'm still confused about how to use the data that is gathered with the script I have above. How will the code in the comment you gave me live inside of the script I already have. Can you show me how you would merge them together so that they function as one program, please?

Comment: @Swan Regarding your encoding error, it's a bit specific to what version of python you're running, but it seems like an encoding issue. I would try:   
        df.to_csv('path_to_save_to.csv', encoding='utf-8')

You probably have a character there that can't be encoded to ascii.
Regarding where to merge the snippet above...I meant for it to replace the for loop in the OP's question.

Comment: @ec2604 Thank you so much! I got it to work finally!

Answer (score 0):

```
import praw
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=,agent_id=,etc.)

submission = reddit.submission(id='7v8ob2')

comments = submission.comments

df_rows = [[comment.parent, comment.id, comment.score, comment.created, comment.body] for comment in comments]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_rows, columns=['Parent ID', 'Comment ID', 'Score', 'Created', 'Body'])

df.to_csv('path_to_save_to.csv')
```

Comment: What is this code? Is it a solution or a supplement to the question? A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.